# Python, Convert non-ascii to ascii based on look-up dictionary

Tags: python

In Python, I need to convert special characters into ascii letters. I have a series of translations in a dictionary

```
dict_trans = {"U+1E9A":"a", "U+1EA0":"a"} # + more

my_char = "ẚ"
```

How do I covert `my_char` into (in this case) `a`?

I can change the format of the characters in `dict_trans` (but to what)?

Comment: @LutzHorn actually it's not, if you zoom in you'll see it's in fact something else. Granted it's not the best example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`unidecode`](https://github.com/iki/unidecode) module, you could use the `unidecode` function.

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode('ẚ')
'a'
```

Comment: This gives me an error, even after installing and importing the module. But it works this way: from unidecode import unidecode; unidecode(u'â'); Any reason I can't use it like that?

Comment: Well, what error? And no, I see nothing against `unidecode.unidecode`.

Comment: Nevermind, the module code only shows this function. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use thes names from [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html):

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.name("a")
# 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A'    
unicodedata.name("ẚ")
# 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING'    
unicodedata.lookup('LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING')
# 'ẚ'

d = {'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING':'a'}
d['LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RIGHT HALF RING']
# 'a'
```

Comment: What I have is a dictionary of several hundred translations. Figuring out the actual character of each one (AND being able type that into my code) may not be so feasible.

Comment: Given the unicode char code `U+1EA0`, you could easily get the corresponding character with `unichr(0x1ea0)` or the escape sequence `\u1ea0` in a string

Comment: (See [Unicode literals in Python source code](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) from the docs)

Comment: @user984003 If you have access to the names of the characters, you can use the approach in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. This more directly answers my question, but I've decided to give the unidecode answer a shot and get rid of my dictionary of translations.

Comment: You could strip off everything after and including any `WITH` in the name and then use `unicodedata.lookup()` to get the character without the added `WITH` part: `''.join(unicodedata.lookup(re.sub(r' WITH .*', '', unicodedata.name(c))) for c in 'ĥáłļø')` → `'hallo'`